# Which one is correct "most experience" or "most experienced"

Tags: sentence-choice

(1) I have done different types of jobs before: accounting, tutoring, cashiering, being a songwriter, and painting. Among these jobs, I **have the most experience** in accounting.

(2) I have done different types of jobs before: accounting, tutoring, cashiering, being a songwriter, and painting. Among these jobs, I **am most experienced** in accounting.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both of these are correct. What makes you think one of them is wrong?

Comment: Why *being a songwriter* and *cashiering*. Would it be the same if you said *songwriting* and *being a cashier*? Or, for that matter, just use the -ing form for all of them.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.